# Extra Conditions on a Laurent Series to Satisfy Certain Statements

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to determine for a Laurent series with coefficients $a_n$ what extra conditions make it true that:

1. $f(z)$ has a pole of order $5$ at $z=0$
2. $f(z) - 7e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has pole of order $5$ at $z=0$
3. $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has pole of order $5$ at $z =0$
4. $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$

What sort of conditions is this referring to?  What values $a_n$ should take on?

Comment: What function are you expanding into Laurent series? Can you be more specific.

Comment: For $\sum a_nz^n$, but there is no specific f(z) in any of the statements below.

Comment: For example, for 1. to be true, assuming the Laurent series is taken around $z=0$, you would need $a_n=0 \hspace{5pt} \forall n<-5$ and of course $a_{-5}\neq 0$.

Comment: This is probably very simple, but why is it $a_{-5}$?  Otherwise it would have a pole of order 6 or higher if $a_{-6}$ was non-zero, right?

Comment: Indeed. The formal justification is a little more long-winded. If there are an infinite number of non-zero $a_n$ for negative indices then the function has an essential singularity at $z=0$ (not a pole). So for it to be a pole, there must be a finite number of these indices. Refer back to your definition of a pole of order $n$, and then prove that all less than $-5$ indices must be zero, and that $a_{-5}$ must be non-zero.

Comment: Right, I had forgotten about that condition!  And so $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity when there are infinitely many $a_n$ for n positive?